# What does Soap UI uses from soap envelope to create XMLDsig signature?

Tags: java, soap, cryptography, soapui, xml-dsig

What does Soap UI uses from soap envelope to create XMLDsig signature? or the opposite question, how can I validate a signature of a Soap XMLDsig response? I'm asking because I only managed to get the proper response using Soap UI.

Let say we have this petition generated in SoapUI:

[image: soapui config signature]

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="..." xmlns:pet="..." xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-...">{BinarySecurityToken}</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature Id="SIG-..." xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dat pet soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-...">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dat pet" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>{Sha1Diest encoded base 64}</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    {Signature encoded base 64}
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-...">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-...">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-..." ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-..." xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <pet:Petition>
            ...data...
        </pet:Petition>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have this java code to generate binary security token (which match the generated by soapui because same certificate), but with the same envelope I get different signature and digest values:

Java code: https://pastebin.com/06NUwkLW

So, what should I use in `String plaintext` to get the proper signature and digest values?

I already tried with a cxf3.4 and axis2 client (using wsdl2java), but adding WS-Security is so complex, and I only find username/password auth, which is not what I need.